# ng-click on body breaks links and input fields on mobile with ngTouch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-touch

Not sure if anybody can help me here, I will probably have to come up with something different but I wanted to sound this issue since I didn't find anything like that here.

I have an app-like website with swipable menu, and I want it to go away whenever user taps somewhere outside the menu. So I've used ngTouch for swiping and attached ng-click="menuToggled = false" to close menu on click/tap.

However if ng-click is attached to body, links in the menu don't work and I cannot focus any of the input fields on the body.

This only happens on mobile devices: iOS or Android (or chrome device emulation).

As I said, I will probably have to think of another solution to close menu on tap, but this issue seems strange to me, perhaps somebody has some thoughts on it.

Here's a simple demo, as I said, it works on desktop but if you enable device emulation with F12 on Chrome you will not be able to focus input field, unless you hold mouse button:

http://jsfiddle.net/L85g3grs/

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-click="showMenu = false">
    <input type="text">
    <button type="button" ng-click="showMenu = true; $event.stopPropagation();">Show menu</button>
    <div class="menu" ng-show="showMenu"></div>        
</body>
```

Comment: can you build a minimal example that demonstrates the behavior? than it is easier to debug what really does not work.. - first thought is that ngClick on body captures the click - but this does not really make sense?!

Comment: @StefanKrüger yes, sorry. When I tried to make a minimal example I've found out that it only happens when ngTouch plugin is included. Updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain the real cause of your original problem.
seems that ng-click on body tag is not a good idea - i think it steals focus in some ways..

i have put together a someway complex solution - but it works on desktop and emulated mobile - tested in Firefox -
and handles the 'click + touch' problem:
[http://jsfiddle.net/s_light/L85g3grs/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/s_light/L85g3grs/4/)

setup the click event on the button:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="menuShow($event)">
    Show menu
</button>
```

and add the handling in your controller:

```
app.controller('MainController',[
    '$scope',
    '$document',
    '$timeout',
function($scope, $document, $timeout) {

    // using deep value so that there are no scope/childscope issues
    $scope.menu = {
        visible: false,
    };

    // our internal clickPrevent helper
    var menu_clickPrevent = false;

    function menuHide(event) {
        console.log("menuHide");

        // set menu visibility
        $scope.menu.visible = false;

        // we need a apply here so the view gets updated.
        $scope.$apply();

        // deactivate handler
        $document.off('click', menuHide);
    }

    $scope.menuShow = function(event) {
        console.log("menuShow", event);

        // check if we are already handling a click...
        if( !menu_clickPrevent ) {
            // stop default and propagation so our hide handler is not called immediate
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();

            // make menu visible
            $scope.menu.visible = true;

            // prevent 'double click' bugs on some touch devices
            menu_clickPrevent = true;
            $timeout(function () {
                menu_clickPrevent = false;
            }, 100);

            // activate document wide click-handler
            $document.on('click', menuHide);
        }
    };

}
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for a working solution. I'll mark it as a correct answer since it works - I myself ended up adding invisible overlay with display: none when menu is minimized and display: block when it's toggled and added hide function on it.